# Upping the default timeout for a PHP application

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP application ([GLPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLPI)) running on Apache.  What is the default session timeout and how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default session time is 1440 seconds (24 minutes).

And you can change it through the configuration files `php.ini` or `.htaccess`.

Using `php.ini`,

```
  session.gc_maxlifetime = 2000;
```

Using `.htaccess`,

```
ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime' , 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the session timeout to 5 minutes by

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5*60);
```

You can check default session timeout by

```
echo $default = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```