# Apache/PHP application sessions timing out

Tags: apache

I am fairly new to PHP and am running an open source web application called GLPI.  We have several users that have the application open all day long and after a while they have to log back on the application.  Is this the Apache session timing out?  If so what is the default and how do I change it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache/PHP application sessions timing out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765072/apache-php-application-sessions-timing-out)

Comment: please don't ask duplicates. In addition to the duplicate, you asked this once before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342966/upping-default-timeout-for-a-php-application Please check out the FAQ on how to get attention for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the session lifetime to a day (24*60*60 seconds):

In your php.ini:

> session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400

In the code:

> ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime' ,86400);

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime